# Why is it faster to allocate memory in the heap for a local array compared to a global array?

Tags: c++, memory-management, global, local

Below is a simple experiment that I decided to run. `test1()` is a function that allocates memory for the global array `g` and then has a for loop that updates all the elements of this array.  Finally it releases the allocated memory for `g`. Exactly the same thing is happening in `test2` but now we use a local array instead called `l`.

```
#include <iostream>
#define n 1000000000
using namespace std;

int *g;

void test1(){
    g = new int[n];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) g[i] = i;
    delete[] g;
}

void test2(){

    int *l = new int[n];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) l[i] = i;
    delete[] l;
}
int main()
{

    timespec cpu_time_s;
    timespec cpu_time_e;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &cpu_time_s);
    test1();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &cpu_time_e);
    long long int ns = (cpu_time_e.tv_sec * 1000000000 
    + cpu_time_e.tv_nsec - (cpu_time_s.tv_sec * 1000000000 
    +  cpu_time_s.tv_nsec));
    cout<<ns<<" ns"<<endl;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &cpu_time_s);
    test2();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &cpu_time_e);
    ns = (cpu_time_e.tv_sec * 1000000000 
    + cpu_time_e.tv_nsec - (cpu_time_s.tv_sec * 1000000000 
    +  cpu_time_s.tv_nsec));
    cout<<ns<<" ns"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I run some tests and I get around `2709066246 ns` for `test1()` and `2459390299 ns` for `test2`

Comment: You should run the tests more often and take the average time. The difference seems rather small compared to the uncertainties that you have when running the test only once.

Comment: Have you tested this with compiler optimization? If not, do so and post the results.

Comment: I run the executable around 20 times and I got the same pattern every time. With compiler optimization (-O3) the pattern is the same.

`571631559 ns` for `test1`
`542970240` ns for `test2`

Comment: Did you try running `test2` before `test1` ? Not sure it would make a difference, though, but I'd try it. Somehow I doubt that local vs. global variable should make a difference in this case.

Comment: ok I did what Kristian suggested and now I am getting the opposite results. Why is this happening?

Comment: Both your tests create array on the heap. It should not affect much with the pointer itself being local or global. As noted by other, it seems within the margin from other uncertainties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the first test run is slower, no matter which it is, then probably the OS takes longer to allocate 4GB and then map it to writable memory on the first pass through. In extremis, it might need to save other things out to swapfile to make RAM available the first time, but not the second. Under light load you'd hope that isn't necessary, but the OS still might have to do something, for example dropping disk cache and re-using the memory it previously occupied. This is fast but not instantaneous.

On the second pass, you've just freed 4GB of memory, all of which has recently been mapped, so there might well be a bit less work to do. The freed 4GB might even still be associated with your process, such that the OS has nothing to do at all, although you'd hope not for a block that large.

You can check by just running `test2` twice, and see whether or not it's consistently slower the first time. If it's generally like this, then it's to do with allocating and writing the array, not to do with details of how you did it.

If the global had been slower regardless of order, then the most obvious possible reason I can think, is that the compiler might not keep `g` in a register, rather it might repeatedly load it out of the globals region. You could check that by looking at the code it emits.

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon is the same as the one I describe in my answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834108/slow-heap-array-performance/27838454#27838454).

TL;DR The OS need to allocate pages when you access the memory you previously allocated. When you free and reallocate, you end up in the same memory region (or nearly the same), and the pages are already allocated by the previous access.

Note that the pages allocation are totally independent of memory allocation. Allocating 4GB does not use 4GB or physical memory until you access it.

To test this, try to access only half the memory on the first loop, and the other half on the second loop. Results should be identical. You can also try to access only odds pages then even pages (pages are 4096 bytes long, 1024 ints).